How to compute the homology of this mapping torus

Compute the homology of $\mathbb{CP}^2\times[0,1]/[z_1,z_2,z_3]\times 0\sim [\bar z_1,\bar z_2,\bar z_3]\times 1$

My attempt is to use the generalisation of MV seriesinn Hatcher example 2.48 for mapping torus $$\to H_n(X)\xrightarrow{1-f_*} H_n(X) \xrightarrow{i_*}  H_n(T_f)\to$$ Note that the mapping degree of $f$ is composition of 3 reflections on $\mathbb S^{5}$(I'm not sure how to descends to $\mathbb {CP}^2$??) so $f_*=-1$ at top degree. Thus we have a LES $$0\to \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb Z\to H_4\to 0\to 0\to H_3\to \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{1-f_*} \mathbb Z\to H_2\to\mathbb 0 \to \mathbb 0\to H_1\to \mathbb Z\xrightarrow{0} \mathbb Z$$. I'm not sure what is $f_*$ at degree $2$, my guess is $f_*=-1$, so $H_4=\mathbb Z_2, H_3=0, H_2=\mathbb Z/2, H_1=\mathbb Z$
(1) Is my solution correct?(especially how to compute $f_*$?)
(2) Other solutions are welcome.

Unfortunately your answer is not quite correct. $f_{*}$ is $Id,-Id,Id$ in degrees $0,2,4$ respectively (all the groups are $\mathbb{Z}$).
To see this notice that conjugation of all homogeneous co-ordinates of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ restricts to conjugation on any affine chart which has one less affine co-ordinate; so it is orientation reversing $\iff$ $n$ is odd. Maybe a good example is $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is restricts as $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ away from the point at infinity so is orientation reversing.
This is all we need to compute. Since $H_{2}(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ is generated by a linear $\mathbb{CP}^1$ for which the restriction of conjugation is again conjugation, this induced map on homology  is $-1$ in degree $2$.
Now putting this information into the sequence(I won't reproduce this here), the homology of the space is: $H_{i}(T_F) = \mathbb{Z} , \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}_2, 0,\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,5$.
It is possible to check that this is compatible with various facts, since f is orientation preserving the $T_f$ is orientable  and hence the degree $5$ homology is infinite cyclic. Also, the fact that $T_{f}$ has a smooth fiber bundle structure $\mathbb{CP}^2 \rightarrow T_f \rightarrow S^1$, implies that the Euler characteristic vanishes.
Also since $H^{1}(T_f,\mathbb{Z})$ is in natural bijection with homotopy classes of maps to circle by Poincare dualtiy $H_{4}(T_f,\mathbb{Z})$ has a geometric description, composing the above fiber bundle with self-maps of the circle with various degrees.

Why $H_2(CP^2)$ is generated by a linear $CP^1$? Is there a reference for generator of $H_k(\mathbb CP^n)$?

See Example 3.40 in algebraic topology by Hatcher

But that's generator for cohomology group

Ok, cell structure is given on example 0.6, then it is explained why this holds for the homology on page 140. The key fact is that the CP^k's in the standard CW structure are linear ones.
